# What is the equivalent of java BCryptPasswordEncoder() in python cli?

Tags: java, python, spring

I have a spring boot web application without registration page or allowing users to register. I'm manually creating passwords using another web spring application which ones gives me encoded password on request.
Using the below link to generate the encoded password: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt

But i was researching to find an alternate simple python equivalent,so i can use it on the cli easily.?

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem, but the following worked for me:

```
bcrypt.gensalt(rounds = 10, prefix=b"2a")
```

This seems to be in sync with the bean `BCryptPasswordEncoder` in SpringBoot :)

Answer (score 0):

BCrypt is a module in python which can be installed using `pip install bcrypt`.
The equivalent to BCryptPasswordEncoder() would require importing bcrypt as `import bcrypt` and then executing `bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())` to encrypt a password.

Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/3.1.0

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I tried compare both output but it seems both are not same. 
Because of the salt generated on the python and java are different. 

On java, this is the function -> 
 public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public void save(xx user){
        user.setPassword(getPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        repo.save(bbouser);
    }

Comment: MohanBabu check the source link. you might get a match.